# Python script to check node / edge coincidence

Tags: arcpy

I have written a script with arcpy to test node and edge coincidence. Each edge (line) should have a node (point) at either end. If this is true, the script does not write anything. If there is node at one end it is marked as closed; if there is not a node at the other end it is marked as open. The script works, but I'd like to optimize it. For 100 edges it is fine, but my dataset has 89,000 edges and it takes over an hour to run:

```
import arcpy
import os

node_featureclass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
edge_featureclass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
filename = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)


openfile = open(folder + (os.sep) + filename + '.csv', 'a')
openfile.write('PIPEobjectID, ERRORtype1, ERRORtype2' + '\n')

nodeDict = {}
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(node_featureclass, ["SHAPE@XY"]):
    nodeXY = row[1]
    nodeDict[nodeXY] = row[0]


for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(edge_featureclass,["OID@", "SHAPE@"]):
    edgeOID = row[0]
    firstPt = row[1].firstPoint
    lastPt = row[1].lastPoint
    firstPointXY = firstPt.X, firstPt.Y
    lastPointXY = lastPt.X, lastPt.Y


for key in nodeDict:
    if nodeDict.has_key(firstPointXY):
        upStreamMH = "CLOSED"
    else:
        upStreamMH = 'OPEN'

    if nodeDict.has_key(lastPointXY):
        downStreamMH = "CLOSED"
    else:
        downStreamMH = 'OPEN'

if upStreamMH == "CLOSED" and downStreamMH == "CLOSED":
   pass
else:
    openfile.write('%i'% edgeOID + ',' + upStreamMH + ',' + downStreamMH + '\n')

openfile.close()
```

Any suggestions on how it might be re-written to make it run faster?

Comment: The first observation I've made is that using cursor objects is notoriously inefficient. 

The second one is that I think some of your spacing may be off in the code section. Should the third for loop be inside the second one?

Comment: @notkilroy, I wasn't aware using cursors from the data access module was inefficient. @Joseph, it probably won't speed up your code, but you should use `with` statements for your [cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001q000000). It looks like your 3rd `for` loop should be nested inside the second, which should be nested inside the first. That's likely the culprit in how long it's taking.

Answer (score 3):

The following should be faster:

```py
points = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(node_featureclass, ["SHAPE@XY"])]

#You don't need OID since it will be covered with i in the for loop.
line_coords = [[row[0].firstPoint, row[0].lastPoint] for row in
               arcpy.da.SearchCursor(edge_featureclass,["SHAPE@"])]

line_start = [(first.X, first.Y) for first,_ in line_coords]

line_end = [(last.X, last.Y) for _,last in line_coords]

#I'm checking if the edge endpoints are in the node feature class. 
#While it might seem a bit backwards....
for i,_ in enumerate(line_start):    
    if line_start[i] in points:
        upstream = "CLOSED"
    else:
        upstream = "OPEN"

    if line_end[i] in points:
        downstream = "CLOSED"
    else:
        downstream = "OPEN"

    if upstream == "OPEN" or downstream == "OPEN":
        openfile.write("{0},{1},{2}\n".format(i, upstream, downstream))    

openfile.close()
```

Feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should seek to make this as SQL and spatial function-based as possible, to avoid using a cursor.

First, create a new edges table that has three columns, edgeOID, firstPoint, and lastPoint from your existing edges table. Then, do two spatial joins of the new edges table to the nodes table, one on the firstPoint column and the other on the lastPoint column

This should result in a table that conceptually contains the following columns: edgeOID, firstPoint, lastPoint, intersectedFirstPoint (could be null), intersectedLastPoint (could be null). Then, you can use a SELECT SQL statement with a WHERE clause that returns all edgeOIDs that have a null in either intersectedFirstPoint or intersectedLastPoint, or both.

Comment: +1 for the SQL approach. Though, I'm still curious why you say cursors are slow. I can read the starting and ending coordinates of 75k lines just shy of 30 seconds. Unless there is a way to populate a table faster than that.

Comment: @Paul, this article http://www.sqlteam.com/article/cursor-performance discusses cursor performance. There are cases where cursors are appropriate, but they are rare.

Comment: @Paul, it should also be noted that slow is a relative term. I'm a Computer Scientist working in a GIS company. What seems really slow to me (loading 75k lines in 30s) seems really fast to my colleagues.

Comment: ahhh yes, I don't have a CS background. If you are using arcpy, cursors are pretty much the only option for reading and writing records. There aren't many other ways in ArcMap to populate a table, sadly. Some of the tools are built on top of cursors, actually (Field Calc being the notable one). Thanks for the link!